# jQuery datatable show span when update successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, datatables

I am using jQuery Datatables, and am working on an inline editing feature. I have been trying to get a green check to show when the record is updated.

Here is the ajax that populates the datatable:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'api/massEditorSummary.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
  {
    var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(data); 
    var table = $('#example1').DataTable({  
      "data": jsonObject,
      "columns": [
        { "data": "partner_name" }, 
        { "data": "service" },
        {
          "data": "forecast",
          "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol)
          {
                $(nTd).html("<input type='text' class='form-control editForecast' 
                id='editForecast' data-uid='"+oData.UID+"' data-editforecast='"+oData.forecast+"'
                value='"+oData.forecast+"' style='width:75px; height:30px;' /> 
               <span id='testID' style='display: none;'><i class='fa fa-check' id='updatedIcon' aria-hidden='true'
               style='color:green;'> </i></span>");
          }
        }
      ],
      "stateSave": true,
      "autoWidth": false    
    });
  },
  error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
  {
    // show fail stuff
  }
});
```

If you'll notice in the data column "forecast", I have a span with an ID set to testID.  This span includes a font-awesome check icon. I initially set it to display: none.

Now I have this update feature that functions on BLUR event:

```
$('#example1').on('blur', 'tr > td > .editForecast', function(e) 
  e.preventDefault();
  var uid = $(this).attr('data-uid');
  var forecastcurval = $(this).attr('data-editforecast');
  var forecastnewval = $(this).val();
  var forecastData = '';

  $.post('api/inlineEditProcess.php', {uid:uid, forecastcurval:forecastcurval, forecastnewval:forecastnewval}, function(data)
  {
    forecastData = data;
    callForecastFunction(forecastData);
  });

  function callForecastFunction(forecastData)
  {
    if(forecastData == "Success")
    {
      $(this).css('display', 'inline-block'); // this is where I want to show the check
    }
    else
    {
      // do fail stuff
    }
  }
});
```

You'll see in the callForecastFunction function, if the data that is returned from the process script equals 'success', then show the check.

Comment: So are you saying that `span id='testID']` is duplicated on each row?  Duplicate ID attribute in html is invalid.

Comment: Is there an error message or nothing happens? I'd console.log `forecastData` and `this` to confirm they are what you think they are.

Comment: Pro-tips for posting: try to keep your questions as succinct as you can. Some of your questions have not been well received, and it may be due to a number of niceties and other chatty material that may seem to you to be polite, but in fact may be interpreted as deferential, obsequious or begging and pleading. This includes thanks, advanced thanks, please-help-me, help-me-out, stuck-for-X-days, I-really-have-googled, hope-it-is-clear, let-me-know-if-need-to-see-more-stuff, it's-really-appreciated, etc. Seasoned helpers would rather just read details of the problem to hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above duplicate `id` attributes are not allowed.  You should fix both the input and span id's.  The span `id` you can base off the UID, for example:

```
"<span id='" + rowData.UID + "' style='display: none;'><i class='fa fa-check' id='updatedIcon' aria-hidden='true' style='color:green;'> </i></span>");
```

You can add additional text to make it more unique.

Then change the selector in your callForecastFunction() to select the span based on the UID:

```
$('#' + uid).css('display', 'inline-block'); // this is where I want to show the check
```

BTW, it looks like you are missing `{` in the event handler function:

```
$('#example1').on('blur', 'tr > td > .editForecast', function(e)
```

Comment: Yes!!!  This is exactly what I was looking for. I wish I could upvote your answer 10 more times. Thank you, sir. Accepted your answer.